# Data from multiple variables in a single column, how to fix?- R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I was given a few hundred excel files where the data was stored in "stylized" format.  When I batch convert the files to .csv and read in the relevant lines, the data from a single file looks like this:

```
 data.frame(x1= c("year", "2014", "site", "28",NA,NA), x2= LETTERS[1:6])
    x1 x2
1 year  A
2 2014  B
3 site  C
4   28  D
5 <NA>  E
6 <NA>  F
```

I want it to look like this:

```
data.frame(year= rep("2014",6), site= rep("28",6), x2= LETTERS[1:6])
  year site x2
1 2014   28  A
2 2014   28  B
3 2014   28  C
4 2014   28  D
5 2014   28  E
6 2014   28  F
```

As you can see, there are 2 variables names (year and site) and their data ("2014" and "28") stored in a single column. (The variable data is always in the row that follows the variable name.)  The other variables in the dataframe, in this case x2, are in the correct format.

Can I ask for some suggestions on how to efficiently get these variables into their own columns?  I'll need to apply the solution to ~100 dataframes of varying length before `rbind`-ing into into 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R:

```
    df <- data.frame(x1= c("year", "2014", "site", "28",NA,NA), x2= LETTERS[1:6], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Make a couple of indexes:

```
year_idx <- which(df$x1 == "year")
site_idx <- which(df$x1 == "site")
```

get their values,

```
year <- df$x1[year_idx +1]
site <- df$x1[site_idx +1]
```

make new columns with the new values:

```
df["year"] <- year
df["site"] <- site
```

rearrange:

```
df <- df[, c(3,4,2)]

stylized_rearranger <- function(df) {
and just do the above steps within and return
df
}
```

Comment: Even simpler still, `df$year<- df$x1[which(df$x1=="year")+1]` and `df$site<- df$x1[which(df$x1=="site")+1]`

Comment: Indeed, always amazed by chained notation, but I find for my purposes that starting simple helps; followed by chaining, once I understand the implications.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the formatting is consistent across files (a big if), you can write code to clean up one file, put it in a function, then use `lapply(files, myFunction) to read in all the files as a list. In your example, named df for convenience:

```
# code to clean data
newdf <- data.frame("year"=df$x1[2], "site"=df$x1[4], "x2"=df$x2)

# wrap this in a function together with read.csv
myFunction <- function(infile) {
  df <- read.csv(infile, as.is=T)
  newdf <- data.frame("year"=df$x1[2], "site"=df$x1[4], "x2"=df$x2)
  return(newdf)
}
```

Then use `lapply`

```
fileList <-list.files(<path>)
# new df names, remove .csv or .xlsx extensions, you may need to do a bit more
dfNames <- gsub("\\..*$", "", fileList)
# get a list of the data.frames
dataList <- lapply(fileList, myFunction)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in my case, but @Chris 's answer is just a little more general by taking advantage of the fixed order of the rows and using their relative indices rather than relying on their absolute index

Comment: Here's the code I used for the loop to create a single dataframe: `files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")` `do.call(rbind, lapply(files, myFunction))`